# Salesforce How to update a roll-up summary field on parent table from inside method that gets triggered when child is persisted

Tags: database, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, soql

> I created a Commission object with field called commission_amount__c, This object has a master detail relationship with Contact. Contact Has a sum up field called Total_Commission__c which sums up all commission amounts from Commissions related to each Contact. I've put a trigger on Commission which calls the method updatePrimary. I want to get each persons total commission but when I query this inside updatePrimary I get the old value in the sumup field(total_commission) and not the new value with the new commission amount added. it hasn't summed up yet. Some help would be very much appreciated if possible.

```
trigger UpdatePrimaryTrigger on Commission__c (after insert, after update) {
    
    
        for(Commission__c c : Trigger.New) {
            ContactHandler.updatePrimary(c);
        }
    }
```

```
public class ContactHandler {
    
    public static void updatePrimary(Commission__c comIn){ 
        
        Contact receiverOfCommission = [Select Name, Total_commission__c
                                       FROM Contact
                                       Where Id = :comIn.Contact__c];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're at the wrong position in the [save order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm#!).

Roll-up summary fields are updated on the parent object at Step 18. `after` triggers are executed at Step 8.

If you want to take action upon the update of your roll-up summary field, you will need to write a trigger on the parent object. However, if I understand your requirement correctly, you may be able to simply place a formula field on the Commission object referencing the roll-up summary field on the Contact.

Comment: Thanks David.I took your advice and wrote the trigger on the parent, That worked for me. :D